# How to add another onclick HTML attribute inside another attribute

Tags: html, events, attributes

I want to use html onclik attribute inside tooltip/title. I allways got Uncaught SyntaxError even i use single or double quotes

Example:

```
<div class="someclass" data-title='<a href="javascript:" onclick="alert('alert')"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'>
     click me 
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can change single quotes inside alert to template literal (es6):

```
<div class="someclass" data-title='<a href="javascript:" onclick="alert(`alert`)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>text</a>'>
  click me
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="someclass" data-title='<a href="javascript:" onclick="alert('alert')"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'>
```

Here is the error you forgot tu put the double quotes after onclick attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your attention but it was my mistake, my problem still exist